# SalesForce API: No such column 'AnnualRevenue' on entity 'Account'

Tags: api, salesforce

While retrieving basic data using the SalesForce REST API, I encountered the following errors. They seem to follow the pattern of; me asking for non-existent fields.

`[{"message":"\nSELECT AnnualRevenue,CreatedDate,Id,LastActivityDate\n       ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:8\nNo such column 'AnnualRevenue' on entity 'Account'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD"}]`

`[{"message":"\nSELECT AnnualRevenue,CreatedDate,ConvertedAccountId\n       ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:8\nNo such column 'AnnualRevenue' on entity 'Lead'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD"}]`

`[{"message":"\nAccountId,Amount,CloseDate,CreatedDate,ExpectedRevenue,ForecastCategoryName\n                                       ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:47\nNo such column 'ExpectedRevenue' on entity 'Opportunity'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD"}]`

But the fields obviously exist, I can see them in the my Dev account. Is it possible that, these fields do not exist for certain types of SalesForce Accounts (Professional, Dev, Ultimate, Enterprise etc)?

To get the application working I removed the fields from the SOQL, and instead used different fields, but not all had replacements. Anyhow... any insight is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super familiar with the REST API, but this sounds like a privileges issue to me.  Are you sure that the account you are using can see these fields?  Check Field Level Security.  I'm pretty sure that Expected Revenue, for example, is invisible by default.

These fields should exist for all versions of Salesforce.

Comment: Good point, I checked that, no luck. The account I used for OAuth is part of the SysAdmin profile.

Comment: Came across this looking for a solution to a similar problem: trying to send new lead data, but getting a 400 (JSON response: ```{
    "message": "No such column 'AnnualRevenue' on sobject of type Lead",
    "errorCode": "INVALID_FIELD"
  }```). We found that the field-level security did indeed have `AnnualRevenue` set to hidden, and unhiding it fixed the issue.